# How to access UITableViewCell that is out of view on a data entry screen to validate content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that contains data entry fields whose total height is about 2 screens tall. After entering data in the fields the user taps the Save button in the UINavigationBar then the contents of all the fields is validated.

If field #1 (topmost) is out of view because the user has scrolled to the bottom of the table then the UITableViewCell that contains the UITextField w/ the value is not accessible. Trying to access the cell/field using cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil.

What would be the best approach to access all the fields in order to validate the field contents?

Comment: Validation of values should generally be done against the model class behind your view, not using the cell views themselves. You should strongly considering an update to your design that doesn't depend on the existence of certain view objects being there.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to store all of the data as it is entered in the fields, and then query your model for the data when you need it, rather than depending on the data being stored in the view.

Comment: The idea behind this is the `MVC` (model-view-controller) code architecture.  I would suggest you do a bit of research on what that is, and how you should implement it if you haven't heard of it yet

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options

1. What I do - store the text from the fields somewhere else and then use that
2. Store all of your cells in memory all the time so that they never get reused
3. Temporarily make your table big enough to hold all of your cells when you're doing the validation

Note that you can do number 3 without the change ever being visible.